# declarar una array's en C# sin tamaño

Tags: c#

Compañeros una pequeña consulta.

¿como puedo declarar un array en c# sin tamaño predefinido?

Comment: si quieres un array sin tamaño predefinido, entonces deberías usar una lista, no un array. si deseas que sea un array, puedes declararlo, pero no lo inicialices hasta que sea necesario.

Comment: Podrias agregar que es lo que llevas de codigo, incluso si este no compila que intentas implementar?

Answer (score 9):

La respuesta corta es

> no

Sin embargo, tienes alternativas para manejarlo, una, sería usar algún tipo de tamaño dinámico como [`List<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Collections.Generic.List%601);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) o [`ArrayList`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Collections.ArrayList);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8), por ejemplo:

```
//Creo una lista..
List<int> miLista = new List<int>();
//Le agrego elementos dinámicamente..
miLista.Add(3);
miLista.Add(7);
miLista.Add(2);
//La convierto en un array
int[] miArray = miLista.ToArray();
```

Si por algún motivo, no queres usar estos tipos que te menciono más arriba, otra posibilidad, puede ser, si bien no es dinámico, hacer uso del método [`Array.Resize`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.array.resize?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Array.Resize%60%601);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8), por ejemplo:

```
int[] miArray = new int[1];
//Agrego un elemento..
miArray[0] = 0;
//Le agrego una posición más
Array.Resize(ref miArray, miArray.Length+1);
//Agrego otro elemento
miArray[1] = 1;
```

Use como fuente, varias respuestas de [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683073/how-to-set-array-length-in-c-sharp-dynamically) en StackOverflow en Inglés.

Answer (score 5):

Puedes hacer uso del tipo de datos `List<>` el cual no defines dimensiones y puedes usar el `Add()` para agregar elementos

[List<> Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.5)

Si al final necesitas del array puedes usar el `ToArray()`

[List<>.ToArray Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.toarray?view=netframework-4.5)

para obtenerlo en base a los elementos del List<>

Answer (score 3):

Pues tal cual, sin indicarle el tamaño, por ejemplo:

```
    string[] arrayTextos;
    int[] arrayEnteros;
```

Cosa distinta es inicializarlo, entonces si que necesitas conocer que capacidad o cuantas posiciones quieres que tenga el array (el rango):

```
    arrayTextos = new string[10];
    arrayEnteros = new int[5];
```

O en el caso en que sepamos lo elementos del array en tiempo de ejecución:

```
    int numeroElementosTexto = 10;
    int numeroElementosEnteros = 5;

    arrayTextos = new string[numeroElementosTexto ];
    arrayEnteros = new int[numeroElementosEnteros ];
```

Puedes ampliar esta información [aquí](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_arrays.htm) (en inglés)

Comment: Pero sino lo inicializas no puedes asignar datos en las posiciones que sentido tiene un array en ese estado? cuando dice "sin tamaño" es porque no conoce cuantos items va a tener, pero debe poder ingresar valores a esa variable, no solo declararla

Comment: @Leandro, entiendo lo que dices, pero creo que entoces deberíamos editar la pregunta y cambiar array por coleccion. Si la pregunta es tal cual, entonces un array puede declararse sin saber de antemano los elementos que pondremos, porque tal vez lo sabremos en tiempo de ejecución.